# R - split Excel workbook into csv files

Tags: r, excel

In R, is there a way to read an Excel workbook and then write each of the worksheets to a separate csv file?  I've looked at the 'xlsx' and 'XLConnect' packages and can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach (with an example Excel file in my working directory called *test.xlsx* with three sheets named Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3):

```r
library(readxl)
library(readr)

# Read sheets and use for filenames
sheets <- excel_sheets("test.xlsx")
filenames <- paste0(sheets, ".csv")

# read_excel only reads a single sheet, so lapply over each sheet name
dats <- lapply(sheets, read_excel, path = "test.xlsx")

# Save each data frame with different filename using write_csv
lapply(seq_along(dats), function(i) write_csv(dats[[i]], filenames[i]))
```

**Edit:** for a function that does this directly given input and output paths, you can do something like:

```r
excel_to_csv <- function(path, out_dir = NULL) {
  if (is.null(out_dir)) out_dir <- dirname(path)
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(path)
  filenames <- file.path(out_dir, paste0(sheets, ".csv"))
  dats <- lapply(sheets, readxl::read_excel, path = path)
  lapply(seq_along(dats), function(i) readr::write_csv(dats[[i]], filenames[i]))
  invisible()
}
```

This saves the CSV files in a specified directory, or if not given, in the same folder as the Excel file.

Comment: Very nice janusvm!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
library(data.table)
library(XLConnect)
importWorksheets <- function(filename) {
  workbook <- loadWorkbook(filename)
  sheet_names <- getSheets(workbook)
  names(sheet_names) <- sheet_names
  sheet_list <- lapply(sheet_names, function(.sheet){
  readWorksheet(object = workbook, .sheet)})
  lapply(sheet_list, as.data.table)
}
```

Basically this will read in the file as a list of data.tables which represent the sheets within the main spreadsheet. You can `rbindlist` these or do whatever you want to them after.